# Map an 'array of objects' to a simple array of key values

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to the mongoDB aggregation pipeline and have a really basic question but could not find the answer anywhere. I would like to simply convert the following block:

```
"exclude" : [
            {
                "name" : "Accenture"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Aon Consulting"
            }
        ]
```

to:

```
"exclude" : [
            "Accenture",
            "Aon Consulting"
        ]
```

using the aggregation pipeline but I cannot seem to find how to do it even after going through the documentation on https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

While @chridam's answer is correct, there is no need to use `$map`.
Simple `$addFields`/`$project` would be sufficient:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            exclude : '$exclude.name'
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 22):

You certainly were in the right direction in using the aggregation framework to handle the transformation. The main operator that maps the object keys in the array to an array of the key values only would be **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** in this case.

Use it together within a **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** pipeline to project the transformed field as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "exclude": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": "$exclude",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": "$$el.name"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

---

In the above, the **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** pipeline stage adds new fields to documents and if the name of the new field is the same as an existing field name (including `_id`), **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** overwrites the existing value of that field with the value of the specified expression.

So essentially the above replaces the `excludes` array with the transformed array using **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)**. **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** works by applying an expression to each element of the input array. The expression references each element individually with the variable name (`$$el`) specified in the `as` field and returns an array with the applied results.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. It works like a charm! Your explanations are also very insightful. Cheers!

Comment: @RaenyvonHaus No worries, happy to help

Comment: Why do we use the double `$` here `"in": "$$el.name"`?

Comment: @Morozov They are used to denote [variables in aggregation expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/)

Comment: How would one go about to make that list unique?

Comment: @rGunti To get a unique list you just run the [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#return-distinct-values-for-an-array-field) query as `db.collection.distinct("exclude.name")`