# How do I created a array field in mongodb from the key values of and object field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I have a document structure like this after a `$project` statement in the `aggregation` framework in mongodb

```
{
  "identificador": "1111111111111",
  "tp": "texto",
  "fotos": 1,
  "qt": 16,
  "dt": "2021-05-13",
  "cdt": "2021-05-24",
  "qt_tags": 2,
  "tags": [
    {
      "k": "text_of_key_1",
      "v": "text_of_value_1"
    },
    {
      "k": "text_of_key_2",
      "v": "text_of_value_2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried `$unwind` but I'm very novice in mongodb and I'm expecting to join all the key or values of the tags array in one new field and get a result like that.

```
{
  "identificador": "1111111111111",
  "tp": "texto",
  "fotos": 1,
  "qt": 16,
  "dt": "2021-05-13",
  "cdt": "2021-05-24",
  "qt_tags": 2,
  "tags_values": ['text_of_value_1','text_of_value_2']
}
```

The document that I used as an example had 2 tags but the documents in the database can have as many tags and they want. How can I do that using the `aggregation` framework

Comment: You can add another `$addFields` pipeline stage which simply does `{ $addFields: { tags_values: '$tags.v' } }`

Comment: Wow, that was super helpful. Please post this as the answer that I will gladly get you the green check!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466409/map-an-array-of-objects-to-a-simple-array-of-key-values

Comment: @YongShun yes! I have already flaged this question as a duplicate